# How to apply Runge-Kutta to an implicit scheme?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, runge-kutta-methods

I see there are some differences in the solution as I increase the resolution of my grid.

I'm using Operator Splitting to solve Diffusion Reaction equation

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \frac{1}{2} \nabla ^2 u = (1-u)u
\end{equation}

Discretised in 1D as:

\begin{equation}
(1-\frac{k}{2}A - \frac{\Delta t}{2}(1-u_E))u(t+\Delta t) = u(t) +\frac{k}{2}Au(t) + \frac{\Delta t}{2}(1-u(t))u(t) 
\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation}
k = \frac{\Delta t}{2(\Delta x  )^2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
    1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 &\ldots & 0 \\
    0 & 1  & -2& 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
    0 & 0  & 1& -2 & 1 & \ldots & 0 \\
    0 & 0  & 0& 1 & -2 & \ldots & 0 \\
    \vdots  &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots & \ddots &\ddots &\vdots \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots &0  &1 &-2
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
u_E= u(t) + k Au(t) + \Delta t (1-u(t))u(t) \\
\end{equation}

Is it possible to apply RK4 on an implicit scheme and improve the accuracy of the solution?

Comment: There are implicit RK schemes _and_ explicit RK schemes..

Comment: RK is applied to ODEs, but you have *already* discretized your time. You should not discretize $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ if you're willing to use RK. The method you're using is simply Euler method, i.e. RK1

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me you already invoked Forward or Backward Euler (cannot really tell, looks not correct to me) to obtain the discretized equation (there is an $\Delta t$ showing up).

What you want is actually something **semi**-discretized, i.e., you want to discretize the spatial derivatives only.

Here, this would imply converting the PDE

$$\partial_t u(t, x) = \frac12 \nabla^2 u(t,x) + \big(1 - u(t, x) \big) u(t,x)$$

via the second order accurate finite differences you propose to

$$U(t)'  = \frac12 k A  U(t) + \big(1 - U(t) \big) U(t) =: F\big(U(t)\big)$$

Now, you have just an ODE (which lacks an initial condition) for which you can use any ODE solver you like.

In particular, you could use RK4, something implicit, ...

Comment: Specifically you almost certainly shouldn't implement time-stepping yourself. Once you've converted to an ODE, use an actual ODE solver which will can do a lot better than RK4